# C++ equivalent for C# Action passing

Tags: c++, anonymous-function

can somebody help me find a solution? I want to know whether there is a C++ equivalent for the following C# code:

```
// C# Code here

private void Execute(Action action)
{
    action();
}
```

Which can be called like this:

```
this.Execute( () => { this.DoA(); this.DoB(); } );
```

Now what I have come up with is to wrap the calls to `this.DoA();` and `this.DoB();` in another method and pass that as a function pointer:

```
// C++ Code here

void Execute(void (*f))
{
    (*f);
}
```

and

```
void DoBoth()
{
    DoA();
    DoB();
}
```

so then it can be called like this, which also works:

```
Execute(DoBoth);
```

But I am looking for a way without having to declare a method `DoBoth`. I know I could just use multiple parameters, but I dont want to restrict the number of the parameters and therefore I was hoping for a way like in C#.

Any help is gladly appreciated.

Comment: Why not pass a list of function pointers and run each one of them?

Comment: @CinCout I would do that but it is rather ugly and unreadable, thats why I was looking for another way

Comment: @PeterDuniho thank you for that, it is what I was looking for. Now do I delete the question or can I close it any other way?

Comment: I doubt your question will be one of those searchable "signpost" duplicates, but if you disagree you can vote-to-close using the same duplicate. Otherwise, deletion seems appropriate.

Comment: I votet to close using the duplicate, and I am going to delete it now. Thank you for your help though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you're looking for is "lambda expression". Basically, it's a anonymous function.

I'll be honest, I have zero experience with C++ lambda.

They've been introduced in C++ 11 it would seem, and take the following form:

```
[]() {}
```

Instead of making plagiarism, I'll redirect you to this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11), which seems to have excellent answers.